# Snowflake SQL Performance question - select

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently we are using snowflake to query the database and curious if the following hinders performance.

Select column_a::varchar(16777216) from view
vs
Select column_a::varchar(100) from view

As you can see the precision is very different. Does this have any impact on performance?

Also what do you call in SQL when someone puts ::datatype?

Please let me know.

Comment: Hi , one thing you will get is the message that would say " String 'string details' is too long and would be truncated ".  The best options is to look at the query profile and see if you are seeing any difference.

Comment: As per snowflake doc's There is no performance difference between using the full-length VARCHAR declaration VARCHAR(16777216) or a smaller length.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer = https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#varchar
There is no performance difference between using the full-length VARCHAR declaration VARCHAR(16777216) or a smaller length.

Comment: Thanks for this. What if we are calling this through Informatica/IICS? If we define metadata there for this huge #, does that make difference?